# Convert a sequence of numbers into a zero based order?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have:

```
var correctOrder = new[] {2, 1, 0};
var actualPositionsFound = new[] {63,62,61];
```

How can I easily convert actualPositionsFound to a zero based sequence?

So if I had:

```
var actualPositionsFound = new[] {100,50,200];
```

I would like to end up with :

```
var result = new[] {1,0,2};
```

**Update:** In an attempt to make this clearer to avoid closing, what I believe is being asked for is to translate a list of numbers into another list of numbers representing the ascending order of the other list like a sort map, 0-based.

So `{ 16, 19, 2, 4 }` would create a map `{ 2, 3, 0, 1 }`, being 0-based.

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: so are you just after `actualPositionsFound.Select(x => x/100)` or is there more logic missing here?

Comment: @Sayse, array length is dynamic and values can be anything.

Comment: @JL. I've attempted to convey what I think you are asking for in an attempt to stave off the close votes because it is unclear. Please review and amend if I am incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no duplicates:

```
var actualPositionsFound = new[] { 100, 50, 200 };
var indices = actualPositionsFound.OrderBy(n => n)
                                  .Select((n, i) => new { n, i })
                                  .ToDictionary(o => o.n, o => o.i);
var result = actualPositionsFound.Select(n => indices[n]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you are looking for?

```
actualPositionsFound.Select((elem, idx) => new { elem, idx })
                    .OrderBy(wrap => wrap.elem)
                    .Select((wrap, idx) => new { wrap.idx, newIdx = idx })
                    .OrderBy(wrap => wrap.idx)
                    .Select(wrap => wrap.newIdx)
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 actualPositionsFound
  .OrderBy(x => x).ToList()
  .Select(x => Array.IndexOf(actualPositionsFound,x)).ToArray();
```

This won't handle duplicates.